# Count occurences after grouping, returning a sequence without summarizing in R

Tags: r, count, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID     Date        result
1      1/1/2010    100
1      1/1/2010    200
2      1/1/2011    300
3      1/1/2011    400
3      1/1/2011    500
3      1/1/2011    600
```

I would like to include another column on this dataframe as such:

```
ID     Date        result  Date_num
1      1/1/2010    100     1/1/2010 (1)
1      1/1/2010    200     1/1/2010 (2)
2      1/1/2011    300     1/1/2011 (1)
3      1/1/2011    400     1/1/2011 (1)
3      1/1/2011    500     1/1/2011 (2)
3      1/1/2011    600     1/1/2011 (3)
```

This seems simple at first since R is quick to group by IDs (using dplyr, table, aggregate, etc), but R is also quick to group everything together and summarize the results.

The first step is to create a vector `c(1,2,1,1,2,3)` that holds the counts in the correct sequence. Then, I could use `dplyr` to `mutate` a new column with it. But the first step has me a little stuck.

I'm thinking:

```
  DF <- DF %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(length(ID)) %>%
    mutate(Date_num = paste(DF$ID, <create a sequence from the previous step?>))
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `row_number()` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 DF %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Date_num = row_number())
```